# Binding Button.IsEnabled to Boolean Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a boolean property that looks at several checkboxes and returns true if any of them are checked.  I would like to enable a button if any checkboxes are checked (property returns true).

Currently I have the following:

- The data context set

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = this;
  }
  ```
- The button binding set

  ```
  <Button Name="button" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabled}">Apply</Button>
  ```
- The property

  ```
  public bool ButtonEnabled
  {
      get
      {
          if(checkboxes_enabled)
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
  }
  ```

I have verified that the property is updating as it is supposed to, so it's narrowed down to a binding issue. I have also tried data triggers within the button:

```
<Button Name="button" Content="Apply">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ButtonEnabled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ButtonEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: So do you have any Binding errors in the output window?

Comment: You are missing a property change notification for the `ButtonEnabled` property. You would typically add that by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or by making `ButtonEnabled` a dependency property. The common MVVM approach would be to create a view model class that exposes the property (instead of the Window), which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: As Clemens mentioned, you will need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then call `OnPropertyChanged("ButtonEnabled")` in the setter of ButtonEnabled (or where ever it needs to be triggered).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

You need `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you are making updates to a property that is bound.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool _buttonEnabled;
    public bool ButtonEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _buttonEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SetButtonEnabled()
    {
        ButtonEnabled = checkboxes_enabled;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged<T>([CallerMemberName]string caller = null) 
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}
```

You should also not have two triggers, and just use a default value.

```
<Button Name="button" Content="Apply">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ButtonEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the following code to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

then call OnPropertyChanged from the property setter

Answer (score 1):

I Would suggest binding the button to a command rather then an event, This way you can just set the command's "canexecute" property to false and disable the whole command that will intern disable the button for you.

I recommend the below tutorial to get a good understanding on WPF commands and how to use them, Once you understand how they work I find they are extremely useful.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM#hdiw1